# Disable italics in emacs org-mode, Ubuntu

Tags: emacs

I am having some trouble disabling the italics in emacs.

I already tried:

```
 '(italic ((t nil)))
```

in `.emacs`. But there is still a problem.

Although it will not italicize the text between `/` and `/`, these `/`s will disappear. So, when I want to write:

```
/home/Quora/
```

it actually shows:

```
home/Quora
```

How can I avoid emacs from trying to change a face, and using the mark-up, when I type `/something/`?

I am using org mode in emacs 24 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/q/695727/151431). If you want this question to be here, please delete your question on [su].

Comment: Is it only in org-mode that you don't want to see italics, or is it in other places too?

Comment: @terdon: del done!

Comment: @JennyD: I only use org mode, shell, dired. In the last two this is not a problem. So, org mode is enough, but I don't mind generally disabling it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

I had to disable the markers //s.

Went to `M-customize-variable RET org-emphasis-alist RET` and deleted the `/` item from the list.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood part of your question. Thanks for posting this answer!

Answer (score 0):

**To disable italic and bold from the customize mode:**

`M-x customize-face RET italic RET`

Unmark the box marked `Slant:`

Then, click `Save for future sessions`

`M-x customize-face RET bold RET`

Unmark the box marked `Weight:`

**To do the same thing in your .emacs:**

```
(custom-set-faces
'(bold ((t nil)))
'(italic ((((supports: slant italic)) nil))
)
```

If there is already a `custom-set-faces` section, just add the middle 2 lines to it.

Comment: That disables italic, but it was already disable. The problem is that with (setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t), the italic markers (//) disappear. So, a dir name /home/ shows up as home.

Comment: Don't do that then :-) 
Instead of using `org-hide-emphasis-markers`, disable italics from the start. Or disable font-lock-mode, that will have the same effect.

Comment: that would have other collateral effects :( I still want to hide the mark-up of  `*bold* ` to show it as **bold**.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `.emacs` file to hide markup.

```
(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
```